# Sonicwall Netextender - I have no idea what to do with this prompt

Tags: windows, vpn

I've been using SonicWALL NetExtender to connect to a server and it's been working for a while, but when I started my pc today [it came up with this prompt](https://i.imgur.com/HW2RcgI.png):

[image]

I thought that I had to change the VPN password, but then I started tabbing through the controls and [it revealed more](https://i.imgur.com/vNZsjQp.png):

[image]

There's also no buttons anywhere on the form to confirm or enter the password/pin/etc.

I've tried re-installing SonicWALL, even going into the registry to remove any trace of it, with no success. I've also searched for any config files that may be storing my old VPN connection credentials but could not find one. What's going on here?

Comment: Most Sonicwall Passwords are related to the user domain password behind the Sonciwall, they are setup using Radius so your password on the Domain has expired and Sonicwall is prompting you to change it however I've not seen this prompt ever work if I'm honest. Who looks after the network behind the Sonicwall if they can reset your password the Sonicwall netextender should just ask for the new one.

Comment: I'll look into what's happening on the server's end, but even using the [commandline](http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/8105/ui2/6000/user_netExtender.html#2168591) doesn't work.

Comment: Since the images have gone.... can anyone replace them with something useful? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what to do; the GUI is broken, but sonicwall still works. You'll just need to use the [command line](http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/8105/ui2/6000/user_netExtender.html#2168591) to connect to a VPN:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender
NECLI connect -s [Server IP address] -u [UserName] -p [Password] -d [Server Domain]
```

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, it seems that this problem was caused by an underlying Internet Explorer problem and resolved by an advanced reset and/or reinstall of Internet Explorer.